# Custom HDPI controls are invisible

Tags: android, user-interface

I have an app, which provides a switchable set of night mode (red) controls using a custom Theme. The controls are in the Shared Preferences view. I have copied and colored all of the necessary images for my controls from Android git sources' hdpi and mdpi folders. The red theme works perfectly fine on the 160 dpi screen (480x800 Android 3.2), but on the 240 dpi one (480x854 Android 2.1) custom check boxes and radios are invisible, they do not occupy any space on the line with label either. Though the drop down list control on a simple linear view seems to be shown perfectly fine. The only difference I can see is that the later one has .9.png images.

What is wrong and how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HURRAY! Found the solution by an accident. I have added a hidden checkbox item to one of the first views of my application, and all of the styled checkboxes magically appeared as they should be in every other view! I believe it's a bug in the 2.1 version of Android. I saw something like that mentioned once while googling for the problem [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12077). It might be irrelevant though.